# Entropy for constant pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, entropy

Is it valid to say that at constant pressure the entropy can be written as follows
$$S=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_{p}~?$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is  **NO**.

Starting with the first law:
\begin{align}
   \Delta Q &= d U  + P dV \\
   T d S &= dU + P dV \\
   dU &= TdS - PdV  \tag{1}
\end{align}
In equation (1), we read that the internal energy varies dependent on the change of $dS$ and $dV$. Therefore, the natural variables for the function $U = U(S,V)$ are $S$ and $V$. Using chain-rule, the differentiation of $dU$ can be expressed as:
$$
dU(S, V) = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_VdS + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_SdV
$$
Comparing chain-rule with Eq.(1), we oabtain two equations:
\begin{align}
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_V &= T;\\
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_S &= -P;\\
\end{align}

`It is not what you are looking for.`

In order to have the form matched your request, we need to do two alternations: (1) change the variable from $S$ to $T$ (2) change the variation from $V$ to be $P$ to be kept a constant. These changes are known as the Legendre Transformation.
\begin{align}
   T dS & = d(TS) - S dT; \tag{2}\\
   P dV & = d(PV) - V dP. \tag{3}
\end{align}

Rewrite Eq.(1) using relations in Eqs.(2) and (3):
\begin{align}
   dU &= TdS - PdV \\
  &= \left\{d(TS) - S dT \right\} - \left\{ d(PV) - V dP \right\}.\\
d(U-TS +PV) & = -S dT + V dP. \tag{4}
\end{align}

Reading from Eq.(4) and compare with the chain-rule, we have:
$$
  S = -\left( \frac{\partial \{U-TS+PV\}}{\partial T}\right)_P = -\left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_P .
$$

The term $\{U-TS+PV\}$ is defined as the Gibbs free energy $G(T, P)$.

Comment: You're missing a minus sign in your last few equations.  dG=-SdT+VdP

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes. Thank you for correction.